# typescript/javascript remove object partial repetition in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have nested array of objects that looks like this:

```js
const nestedArray = [
   [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
   [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
   [{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }],
]
```

Since objects with id 1 and 2 are already together in `nestedArray`'s first element I want to remove the second element and maintain other elements without petition as they are. The result should be like this:

```js
const nestedArray = [
   [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
   [{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }]
]
```

How do I write a filter function by `id` to get the expected result?

Comment: On id can work.

Comment: 1) are `id` unique in each sub array ? 2) all elements of the second sub array exist in the first sub array, must we deduce that it suffices that if the first element exists in the preceding subarray, then all the others are?  3) Do duplicate subArray only exist in the previous subArray?

Comment: No, I was sleeping. :D 1) Yes, `id`s are unique in sub arrays, objects with same `id` in different sub arrays are the same object. 2-3) More likely duplicated objects are in sub array next to each other, at the moment I'm woking with a small bunch of data and I'm not sure. But I think I can sort the elements before grouping them so duplicates will be next to each other. In general the removal condition is that in the nested array there's another sub array with exact same or more elements. For example if the second array would have been [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 4 }] it could have stayed...

Comment: ... because there's not another sub array that contains the same elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your example:

1. the `id` are unique in each subarray
2. duplicate sub-array elements only exist in the previous sub-array
3. if the first element of a sub-array exists in the previous sub-array   then all the other elements must also be

```js
const nestedArray = 
  [ [ { id: 1} , { id: 2} , { id: 3} ] 
  , [ { id: 1} , { id: 2} ] 
  , [ { id: 4} , { id: 5} , { id: 6} ] 
  ] 

function arrCleaning(arr)
  {
  for (let i=arr.length;i--;)
    {
    if (i>0 && arr[i-1].some(x=>x.id===arr[i][0].id) )
      arr.splice(i,1)
    }    
  }

arrCleaning( nestedArray )

// result
console.log( 'nestedArray = [' )
nestedArray.forEach(e=>console.log('  ',JSON.stringify(e).replaceAll('"',''),','))
console.log('  ]')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without flatting the nestedArray? Like `[ [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, ] ]`. I need to maintain the structure for the next step.

Comment: Sorry, probably I over simplified my problem. There're also other elements in the `nestedArray` which are also grouped. The reason why cannot flat the `nestedArray` is because I need to maintain this grouping. If I flat `nestedArray I can regroup the elements again but I always end in the same situation with the repetitions.

I updated my question.

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: It works! I just made a small change to the `if` condition because my example was still missing of a case but the idea of your code is what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const nestedArray = [
   [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
   [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
]

var newArr = nestedArray.flat(2).filter((x, index, self) => index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.id === x.id)));
console.log(newArr);
```